# Why did Yamamota want to go against the Army?

Tags: plot-explanation, midway-2019

A car stops at a building and Yamamoto gets out as he is
greeted by Yamaguchi. They talk about Nagumo:

> Yamaguchi: Someday that old fool will make an even bigger mistake.
>
> Yamamoto: None of that talk inside. **We must be united against the
> Army**.
>
> Yamaguchi: I'm not Nagumo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inter-service rivalry is fairly common around the world - though it is usually a simple case of services/units believing themselves to be the best.

However, a long standing historical narrative has been that the rivalry between the Imperial Japanese Army (IJA) and Imperial Japanese Navy (IJN) was particularly egregious and deep. It began almost immediately at their inception in 1868 - mainly as a fight over funding and resources, which came to a head in the 1920s. The Navy wanted more, larger ships - which are costly. The Army was worried they'd be underresourced - Japan wasn't the powerful economy it became after WWII.

The 1930s saw the Army gain much prestige with the invasion into China. A continuing mainland invasion would reduce the importance of the Navy, and threaten their funding.

The rivalry simply worsened all the way to the end of the war in 1945.

Comment: Not that I doubt your word - but a couple of citations for this would turn a good answer into a great one :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Unfortunately, I can find no online references except Quora/Reddit discussions, and I can't remember and do not own the books I read it in. It may be this is a Western narrative to highlight why it was inevitable that the Japanese lost in the Pacific - but that narrative still informed this movie (and previous similar movies)

Comment: OK, no worries.

Comment: The book "Shattered Sword: The Untold Story of the Battle of Midway" by Anthony P. Tully & Jonathan Parshall contains plenty of information on this subject.